# NetworkManager issues in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, networkmanager

Have had WiFi working fine via wifi-menu on command line for a while, but would much prefer the gnome icon, so i switched to NetworkManager, and now nothing will connect.
I enabled my dhcp daemon in the config file, but the issue seems to happen before that point... any network I try it just refuses to connect to. It sees networks, then fails to connect immediately on click.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the Arch Linux Wiki page on NetworkManager.

If `NetworkManager` is going to be handling any/all network devices. Then you should not have anything but `NetworkManager` enabled. If you have **any** `net-auto-wireless` services enabled they will have to be disabled.

`# systemctl stop net-auto-wireless.service`

`# systemctl disable net-auto-wireles.service`

You will then have to bring down your Network Interface Controllers. If you're using the new naming scheme then use `ip l` to display the interface names and bring them down.

For each interface listed (wired, wireless):

`# ip link set <interface> down`

Once down, enable NetworkManager and start NetworkManager:

`# systemctl enable NetworkManager`

`# systemctl start NetworkManager`

***Note:*** If you have services which **fail** if they are started before the network is up, you have to use `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` instead. This is however hardly ever necessary since most network daemons start up fine, even if the network has not been configured yet.

Also: I believe `extra/networkmanager` does **not** supply the gnome applet. If not it will be in `extra/network-manager-applet`

`# pacman -Syu networkmanager network-manager-applet`

Comment: -1 for copying from arch wiki without referencing it. Plagiarism in small.

Comment: The first sentence is weird... If it means to say "any", why include "all"?

Answer (score 2):

First stop NetworkManager and anything that has to do with networking:

`# systemctl stop NetworkManager`

`pgrep -l dhc` (stop the services or kill the processes for these)

`ps aux | grep -i wicd | grep -v grep` (same with these)

Then start NetworkManager again, and wait for a few seconds.

`# systemctl start NetworkManager`

Use the network-manager-applet if you like. See if you can connect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and have tried all suggestions on the net but in the end it was enough to install `dhclient` to solve my problem.

Comment: I don't know why you downvoted this answer, actually it solved my problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, NetworkManager doesn't prompt you to enter the password for protected network. If you're trying to connect to a protected network, edit the network from GNOME Control Center and set the network's password. Then, connect to the network.